# XSL-FO add new line after each node

Tags: xml, xslt, pdf, xsl-fo

I have an XML file with structure like this:

```
<parent>
    <node>Text 1</node>
    <node>Text 2</node>
    <node>Text 3</node>
    <node>Text 4</node>
    <node>Text 5</node>
</parent>
```

I want to process this XML with XSL-FO to produce PDF output. I have following XSL-FO template:

```
<fo:block>
    <xsl:for-each select="node[position() &lt; last()]">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
            <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</fo:block>
```

It seems that this doesn't work well. I get output inline, instead of each node in it's own line. How can I resolve this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

use

```
<fo:block  linefeed-treatment="preserve">
```

Answer (score 1):

You would have better control of things if you matched on the node element and created an fo:block for them. The solution you have is for putting them inline, the other answer will work but yield less control of them.

If you want each one in a new line (which means you want a new block area), then put each one is it's own block.

Meaning, you would do somewhere in your XSL:

```
 <xsl:template match="node">
     <fo:block>
         <xsl:apply-templates/>
     </fo:block>
 </xsl:template>
```

There should be no reason for you to use value-of select=".". The above will do that for you and if you ever expand to have something inside of the node element, then your are still all set.