# Page break inside table XSL-FO

Tags: xslt, pdf-generation, xsl-fo

I have an XSL-FO stylesheet for a table.

```
<fo:page-sequence master-reference="defaultPage">
  <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
    <fo:table table-layout="fixed" width="100%">
      <fo:table-column column-width="9pt"/>
      <fo:table-column column-width="30pt"/>
      <fo:table-column column-width="150pt"/>
      <fo:table-header>
        <fo:table-row>
          <fo:table-cell>
            <fo:block><xsl:text>Column 1</xsl:text></fo:block>
          </fo:table-cell>
          <fo:table-cell>
            <fo:block><xsl:text>Column 2</xsl:text></fo:block>
          </fo:table-cell>
          <fo:table-cell>
            <fo:block><xsl:text>Column 3</xsl:text></fo:block>
          </fo:table-cell>
        </fo:table-row>
      </fo:table-header>
      <fo:table-body>
        <fo:table-row>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="rbrOcjena"/>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="sifPred"/>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="nazPred"/>
        </fo:table-row>
      </fo:table-body>
    </fo:table>
  </fo:flow>
</fo:page-sequence>
```

The table can have many rows, so I'd like to break it on new page when it comes to the end of current, when generating PDF. Also, I would like to repeat table header on new page, if that's possible. What attributes should I put in the table tag to make it so?

Thanks!

Comment: Before asking a new question, please accept an [answer to your last question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24938287/1987598). Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> The table can have many rows, so I'd like to break it on new page when
>   it comes to the end of current

Without seeing your XSL-FO code, it is difficult to answer this. Please show it. But generally, this is done with keeps and breaks. For example:

```
<fo:table-row keep-together.within-page="always">
```

---

> I would like to repeat table header on new page, if that's possible.
>   What attributes should I put in the table tag to make it so?

Instructing an XSL-FO processor to repeat a number of rows at the top of every page is not done via an attribute to `fo:table`. Instead, the rows that are to be repeated are put inside `fo:table-header`:

```
<fo:table-header>
   <fo:table-row>
      <fo:table-cell>
         <!--Block and text content-->
      </fo:table-cell>
   </fo:table-row>
</fo:table-header>
```

Then, the default behaviour of the processor should be to repeat the header rows after a page break. That's because the `omit-header-at-break` attribute of `fo:table` is [set to "false" by default](http://www.w3.org/TR/xsl/#table-omit-header-at-break).

The most obvious reason for this is that it is immediately clear which rows belong to the header and should thus be repeated. If this was just a reference in an attribute of `fo:table` it would be harder to identify multiple rows as the header. You will find the relevant part of the XSL specification [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/xsl/#fo_table-header).

Comment: Hi and thanks for your answer. I edited my question and provided more detailed XSL-FO code, can you please look at it again.

Comment: @sty2000 Not only the page sequence. Please provide a full XSL-FO document that I can test. Also, did you see the comment I have placed below your question?

Comment: Here it is: [link](http://pastebin.com/sxDeDs5n). I posted it like this because it's quite big. And I also think that you won't be able to test it because it's getting some of the data from server you don't have access to.

Comment: Also, I realized that the problem may not be with the table. Somehow, after page 3 it stops generating next pages, I can't realize why?!

Comment: @sty2000 Yes, I can't test your XSLT code. Then, I cannot possibly help you. But I agree that the table is not at fault. Note that it's considered good manners on Stackoverflow to accept answer that were helpful, for example [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24938287/1987598).

Answer (score 1):

I've faced similar scenario...

Try below code...

```
 <fo:table-row>
    <xsl:if test="position() != 1">
    <xsl:attribute name="break-before">page</xsl:attribute></i>
.
.
.
```

Comment: That adds a page break before every row except the first. Sty2000 just wants the table to break when the page is full, and there is no need to add an explicit break to do that.